# How can I create a typed collection class in Knockout mapping?

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using knockout with the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) so that I can write code like this:

```
function ContactViewModel() {
    //other properties...
    this.emails = ko.observableArray();
}

function ContactEmailViewModel() {
    //other properties...
    this.address = ko.observable();
}

var koContactMap = {
    'emails': {
        create: function (options) {
                    return new ContactEmailViewModel(options.data);
        }
    }
};

var model = new ContactViewModel();
ko.mapping.fromJS([JSON data from web service], koContactMap, model);
```

In English, I have `contacts` and `emails`, and a `contact` has `emails`.

This works perfectly, and I can load the contact and have the data and emails populated, and the emails are of type `ContactEmailViewModel`, as I want.

But the thing I'm confused about is: why does the map create method return a **singular** email object instead of a **collection** of email objects. The `emails` property is a collection, but seems to be populated by returning a single object, and is called multiple times, once for each member.

This correctly populates the `emails` property. But now I want to change `emails` from an array to an `EmailsList` object, so that I can give it methods, and I can't see how to do this, since the create method returns individual emails, not the whole emails property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that behaviour you can add `ignore` on the emails propery and let the mapping plugin serperate map the emails into a standar array that you feed the EmailsList constructor with.

```
var emailMapping = {
   create: function(opt) {
      return new Email(opt.data);
   }
};

this.emails = new EmailList(ko.mapping.fromJS(arr, emailMapping));
```

Hmm, you could also extend a custom class with a observableArray I think (havent tested) that ko.mapping will then just add emails to your EmailList like

```
this.emails = new EmailList(); //This is is a ko.observableArray the mapping plugin will populate it with emails
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingInfo, this);
```

https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observableArray.js

update: I just confirmed that solution two worked, so I would say thats a good way of doing it

http://jsfiddle.net/xop2go2z/

```
//stolen from ko source
function setPrototypeOf(obj, proto) {
        obj.__proto__ = proto;
        return obj;
    }

ko.MyList = function(arr) {
    var result = ko.observableArray(arr);
    return setPrototypeOf(result, ko.MyList.fn);
}

ko.MyList.fn = {
    pushMyThingy: function(obj) {
        this.push(obj);
    }
};
```

Comment: I know how to do the `ignore`, but I don't see where you would put the code to create and return the EmailsList object, and where it would get the email object data from. Could you suggest some code to do that?

Comment: See update, verbose, but I think its the only way with current version of mapping

Comment: See possible second solution